# Setting up Tomcat with pre-existing MySQL from WAMP

Tags: mysql, tomcat

I have Tomcat running on 8080 port and WAMP's apache on port 80.

Can I use Tomcat with the existing MySQL setup?

How do I go about it? I have downloaded the mysql connector java 5.1.13.

System Details:
WinXP Pro SP3
WAMPSERVER 2 with Apache 2.2.11 & MySQL 5.1.41
Tomcat 6.0.29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason why not. The ports Apache and Tomcat are listening on have nothing to do with the MySQL connection.

Comment: I would have loved to mark this as an answer, if it gave more details. But since there are no other answers, wth.

Comment: Ah, yes. When it comes to hooking Tomcat to MySQL, I'm hopeless; I can only address the first part.